# Dropdown menu not stretching vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stretch the sidebar vertically when the dropdown is clicked. The height of the sidebar is 100%, so if I click the link or the `a` tag, the sidebar should stretch.

However, if I click the sidebar the container and the sidebar stays at 100% height and the dropdown goes past the end of the menu.

In the picture there are 4 links as an example, but in the code below I've only added 1 link.

The first image: This is when the links or the `a` tag is not been click

The second image: This is when the links are already clicked and the sidebar and container does not stretch.

[image: This is when the links or the a tag is not been click][image]

```
<body>
<!-- SIDERBAR -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
        <img src="images/1232.png" class="logo">
        <h1 class="h1-1">Pacific Sky</h1>
        <h1 class="hr-1">___________________________</h1>
        <img src="images/sampleimg.png" class="dp">
        <p class="welcomemessage">Welcome, <p class="adminname">Dave Spencer</p>

        <div class="links">
        <br>
            <h5 style="color: white; font-size: 2vh;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;GENERAL</h5><br>

            <!-- Links -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/showhide.js"></script>
            <!-- links palatandaan -->

            <div class="dashboard" id="dashboard">
            <p class="dashboard-color">&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <i class="fa fa-podcast" aria-hidden="true" id="dashboardlogo"></i>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            DASHBOARD 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down okay" aria-hidden="true" id="downlogo"></i></p>

            <a href="" class="dashboardlinks"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" id="bullet"></i> Messages</a>
            <a href="" class="dashboardlinks"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" id="bullet"></i> Pending Reservation</a>
            <a href="" class="dashboardlinks"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" id="bullet"></i> Approved Reservation</a>
            </div><br>
</div>
</div>

    // showhide
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dashboard").click(function(){
        $("a").slideToggle(400);
    });
});         


*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body
{
    width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans';
}
a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
    font-family: RobotoT;
}
.container
{
    background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #ccccff 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar
{
    width: 50vh;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2A3F54;
}

//and this is the links


 .links
{
    position: relative;
    top: 33%;
    color: #e5e6e8;
}
.dashboardlinks
{
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    line-height: 250%;
    text-align: left;
    color: #e8eaef;
    position: relative;
    top: 1vh;
    padding-left: 14%;
}
#downlogo
{
position: absolute;
right: 8%;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your js too so that way we can expand the html to see the menu effect?

Comment: Also clean up your code `id"downlogo"`

Comment: already updated sir! @PaigeMeinke

Comment: @Huangism y sir?

Comment: @DaveSpencerSanchezBacay why clean it up? so it makes sense `id="downlogo"`

Comment: @DaveSpencerSanchezBacay You have a relative link to it, but it's not accessible on the web in the code snippet you provided.

Comment: what do you mean sir? @PaigeMeinke sorry sir im currently newbie here in web.

Comment: @Huangism done sir.

Comment: @DaveSpencerSanchezBacay `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showhide.js"></script>` is a relative link. It goes to a folder on your computer. For us to access it and see it, you need to post a web link like `<script type="text/javascript" src="www.linkhere"></script>` or post the raw code in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just need to change width to height:  (and I'd add html)

```
body
{
    width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans';
}
```

to

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `.sidebar` to this

```
.sidebar
{
    width: 50vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2A3F54;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmuhnhfo/

I just copy pasted more items in fiddle to make it show the issue

The height 100vh before is restricting it and since you want it to stretch the whole way, just set minimum height

On a side note, you should change

```
<p class="welcomemessage">Welcome, <p class="adminname">Dave Spencer</p>
```

to

```
<p class="welcomemessage">Welcome, <span class="adminname">Dave Spencer</span></p>
```

I think you originally you had a `p` tag inside of another `p` tag